# Caused by: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, microservices, resttemplate, netflix-zuul

I am trying to call an external microservice using RestTemplate. But it is failing because I am using UserDetails.class as responseType. I know that UserDetails is an interface and it can not be constucted. But I tried with custom classes also, Even I tried with **User.class** instead of UserDetails.class. but it didn't work. Please see the example below:

**API name zuul-service**

```
UserDetails userDetails = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8001/login/getUserDetails?username=" + userName, UserDetails.class);
```

and this is what I am trying to call:
**API name login-service**

```
@GetMapping("/login/getUserDetails")
public ResponseEntity<UserDetails> getUSerDetails(@Param("username") String username) throws Exception 

{
        LOGGER.info("Start getUSerDetails::LoginController " + username);

        final Login userDetails = loginUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

        LOGGER.info("Start getUSerDetails::LoginController " + userDetails.getUsername());


        return ResponseEntity.ok(new User(userDetails.getUsername(), userDetails.getPassword(), new ArrayList<>()));
}
```

I don't know what I should try now and how it will work. Please help me on this.

Comment: your service under path `/login/getUserDetails` is returning a ResponseEntity of User, so what you should use to receive the response is a User class and it should contains default constructor!

Answer (score 0):

finally your code should be like:

```java
UserDetails userDetails = (User) restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8001/login/getUserDetails?username=" + userName, User.class);
```